# GCP DataflowRunner ImportErrors

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, apache-beam

Code is working when using option DirectRunner. But getting import errors when switching it to DataflowRunner. lxml module is not found is the reason. When trying to use setuptools code along with the main code, its still not working ( --setup_file setup.py).

```py
setuptools.setup(
    name='lxml',
    version='4.2.5',
    install_requires=[],
    packages= setuptools.find_packages(),
)
```

Error: ImportError: No module named lxml [while running 'Run Query']

Any help/suggestions to overcome this error? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The `name` you pass to the `setuptools.setup` function is the name of *your* package, and its dependencies should be specified in the argument `install_requires`. I would imagine it works with the `DirectRunner` because the package is installed on your local machine.

The Beam [juliaset](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/b9e6fa149c50665fdc796080e4fa8f43b0b0432b/sdks/python/apache_beam/examples/complete/juliaset/setup.py#L116) example provides a sample setup.py file:

```
REQUIRED_PACKAGES = ['numpy']
setuptools.setup(
    name='juliaset', # this is their package name
    version='0.0.1',
    description='Julia set workflow package.',
    install_requires=REQUIRED_PACKAGES,
    ...)
```

#### PyPI dependencies

If `lxml` is your only dependency, or all your dependencies are on PyPI, you should be able to use the much simpler requirements.txt file. In general, the setup.py approach requires much more boilerplate.

To use requirements.txt, freeze your dependencies:

```
pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

And pass the requirements.txt file to your pipeline:

```
--requirements_file requirements.txt
```

See also the Beam documentation's page for [various dependency patterns for Python](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/sdks/python-pipeline-dependencies/#pypi-dependencies).

Comment: Thanks for answering my query. I realized my mistake and used requirements file later. And its working as expected.

Comment: Glad the issue is resolved, please consider to accept the answer.